# C#: Running multiple requests synchronously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, winforms

I am trying to get multiple browsers to run tasks at the same time. I created a sort of test application just to see if I could do it as a task to myself. I was doing well but it seems like its slowed down a lot and that its waiting for the first browser to finish before the second one loads the page.

Before anyone suggests using another other than WebBrowser I would just like to say that my decision to chose a WebBrowser has good reasons.

I have a class called "Slave" to run a request to Google, I create them using the code shown below:

```
public void LoadSlaves()
{
    for (int i = Program.GetServer().GetConfigHandler().GetValueByKeyInt("slaves_count"); i > 0; i--)
    {
        _slaves.Add(_slaves.Count, new Slave());
    }

    Logger.Warn("Loaded " + _slaves.Count + " slaves.");
}

public void StartSlaves()
{
    foreach (var slave in _slaves.Values)
    {
        slave.Start();
    }
}
```

Class:

```
using NLog;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test.Root.Base.Slaves
{
    class Slave
    {
        private static readonly ILogger Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        private Thread _slaveThread;
        private WebBrowser _browser;

        public Slave()
        {
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _slaveThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnCycle));
            _slaveThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            _slaveThread.Start();
        }

        public void OnCycle()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_browser == null)
                {
                    _browser = new WebBrowser();
                    _browser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
                    _browser.DocumentCompleted += browser_DocumentCompleted;
                    _browser.Navigate("http://google.com");

                    Application.Run();
                }
            }

        }

        private void browser_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (_browser.Url == e.Url)
            {
                Logger.Trace("Navigated to {0} on " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, e.Url);
                _browser.Navigate("http://google.com");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Heres some logging:

```
  22:17:56 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=f0KfWZ29L8HHXo_vm_gI&gws_rd=ssl on 7
  22:17:58 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=gkKfWdzoAcjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 8
  22:18:01 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=g0KfWaffJMjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 7
  22:18:02 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=hUKfWd33KMjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 8
  22:18:06 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iUKfWf6xE8jHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 8
  22:18:07 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=iEKfWfPPFMjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 7
  22:18:10 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jUKfWcHGLMjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 7
  22:18:12 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=jUKfWdbLB8jHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 8
  22:18:15 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kEKfWezHPMjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 7
  22:18:16 - Navigated to https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=kkKfWe35OcjHXpyEl2g&gws_rd=ssl on 8
```

As you can see its waiting a few seconds between requests (2-3 seconds usually), how can I get both browsers to run at the same time synchronously?

Comment: `Before anyone suggests using another other than WebBrowser I would just like to say that my decision to chose a WebBrowser has good reasons.` Could you share those good reasons with us, just in case there is a better alternative?

Comment: I need total control of the request. I need to visit a website, login, visit another page, type something into a textbox and then click a button. I need to do this in repeat to test how long it takes and do it at the same time on multiple threads. I can't use anything such as WebClient or HttpPost for obvious reasons, that and the fact the login as a authenticity token system that can't be easily spoofed.

Comment: Use Selenium and you will have all those capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Could you be getting slowdowns because the thread started never closes. It doesn't look like you need it anymore yet it's still looping. I haven't used WebBrowser before but, with any thread that your done with you should let it finish gracefully unless there is a good reason not to.
Would something like this work for you?

```
    ...

    public void OnCycle()
    {
        while (_browser == null)
        {

    ...
```

Also just for clarification is it only getting slow with a lot of _slaves running?

Comment: I were running two slaves at the time of that logging. I keep it running as I constantly want to be running checks so I can judge the average time and make it as accurate as I can, I also want to see how speed reduces and increases during the requests.

Comment: So from what I understand the Application.Run(); should be the only thing you need to keep this recursion going right? It's only called once do you need to keep the thread open and looping while recursion is happening?